# Combined Spring Boot integration & web application won't start

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-web

I have created two Spring Boot applications. One uses Spring Integration to read stuff from several feeds and the other combines the retrieved data from the feeds on a simple web page.

Currently these two exist as separate apps but I want to combine the two in a single application. The integration "application" is nothing more than a integration.xml and the other one is a couple of RestControllers.

In my Application class the integration application has the following in the main method:

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplication("/feed/integration.xml").run(args);
    System.out.println("Hit Enter to terminate");
    final int read = System.in.read();
    System.out.println("Closing! (" + read + ")");
    ctx.close();
```

The web application has

```
    SpringApplication.run(MyWebApplication.class, args);
```

I've tried to combine the two resulting in:

```
    try {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplication("/feed/integration.xml").run(TrailerListApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hit Enter to terminate");
        System.in.read();
        ctx.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but that only starts the web application. The feeds don't get initialized. How can I make sure both components start and keep running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@ImportResource("classpath:/feed/integration.xml")` to `MyWebApplication` and just use

SpringApplication.run(MyWebApplication.class, args);

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: It works when I run it from IntelliJ, but when I package it I get this error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/feed/integration.xml] but only as part of the tests...

Comment: That totally fixed it. Now I can include tests in the packaging.